# Regex to match telephone numbers with 00 and + and also allow spaces

Tags: regex

I created this regex that works for what I want:

```
^(?:00|\+)[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{6,14})$
```

However it does not work when someone has spaces in the phone number.

Works for: +14917672662642
Does not work for: +14917 67 266 264 2

How could I Adapt this to allow spaces in the phone number?

My test: https://regex101.com/r/rhwOBt/1

Would this be the best way to do it:

```
^(?:00|\+)([0-9]|(\s\S))?()[0-9](\s|\S)+(\d[0-9]{6,14}|(\s|\S)+)$
```

Comment: Do you need the info conveyed by whitespaces ( eg. for distinguishing between area code, trunk line, extension)? Otherwise you could remove spaces before regex matching.

Comment: well the way validation done is a little more complicated, so would prefer just to ignore white spaces instead of removing them before regex checking

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know exactl which phone numbers you are about to encounter, the regex should not be too smart - ie. have it recognize a string of digits interspersed with whitespace and the international dialling prefix (like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/NzHDEl/2): `^(?:00|\+)[0-9]+(?:\s*[0-9]+)+$`.

There are a host of conventions on how to write down a phone number and depending on the network/territory it relates to, there are a lot of different ways phone numbers are structured. Cramming that into a single regex will be a nightmare to maintain.

Typos are to be expected, ie. whitespace at positions they should not occur based on the structure of the phone number; some sort of post-match validation will be necessary anyway which most certainly will not preserve whitespace at the original position.